# Setting up PerformancePoint Services on Sharepoint 2010: connection errors

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have tried to setup PerformancePoint Services on SharePoint 2010, but every time I try to use the dashboard designer, I get this error:

“An error has occurred attempting to contact the specified SharePoint site”

I have tried [these steps](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/d91dfbc9-a91f-47fc-9cae-06373283517c/) but it hasn't helped.
Any ideas?

The event log gives the following information:

> WebHost failed to process a request. 
>   Sender Information:
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/24724999
>   Exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException:
>   The service '/_vti_bin/client.svc'
>   cannot be activated due to an
>   exception during compilation.  The
>   exception message is: This collection
>   already contains an address with
>   scheme http.  There can be at most one
>   address per scheme in this collection.
>   Parameter name: item. --->
>   System.ArgumentException: This
>   collection already contains an address
>   with scheme http.  There can be at
>   most one address per scheme in this
>   collection.  Parameter name: item
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.UriSchemeKeyedCollection.InsertItem(Int32
>   index, Uri item)    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.SynchronizedCollection`1.Add(T
>   item)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.UriSchemeKeyedCollection..ctor(Uri[]
>   addresses)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type
>   serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type
>   serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[]
>   baseAddresses)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String
>   relativeVirtualPath)  Process Name:
>   w3wp  Process ID: 2576

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar error. 
Have looked through the file c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14\isapi\client.svc (this guy is pulled when '/_vti_bin/client.svc' is called.) its content is

but the assembly Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c does not contain a definition for the class Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestService

Can anybody explain the situation?

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 bindings in IIS for my SharePoint site the designer was trying to connect.
After I have removed the second one and only 1 left, the Dashboard Designer stoped throwing errors and had started working just fine.

So the problem is still unclear for me, but it has been particularly resolved.